# Erorr while using tkinter package

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, python-packaging

I get an error while using the `grid` method in `tkinter` package.
I already used `tkinter` in projects, so I have no idea why I get this error.

**Input:**

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
logo_image = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_image)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)

# Labels
website_label = Label(text="Website:")
website_label.grid(colmun=0, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kfirs\PycharmProjects\Day 29 project - Password Generator\main.py", line 61, in <module>
  website_label.grid(colmun=0, row=1)
  File "C:\Users\kfirs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2522, in       grid_configure self.tk.call(_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-colmun": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misspelling option "`-colmun`":

```
# Labels
website_label = Label(text="Website:")
website_label.grid(colmun=0, row=1)
```

Change it to `column` and everything should work!

It already show in your error trace:
`File "C:\Users\kfirs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2522, in       grid_configure self.tk.call(_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-colmun": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky`